# MySQL custom sorting based on priority

Tags: mysql, laravel, sorting

Rank table:

```
id | university_id | application_id | pts | year | priority
```

A student applies for Erasmus and chooses 3 universities ordered by priority.
Then points for each university selection are generated based on some criteria, and saved to the above table. Universities accept a maximum number of students.

I want to get a list with universities and students who are accepted with MySQL.

**Example**:
10 students apply for Erasmus to 2 universities. The university A can accept 6 students & university B 5. 8 students applied with university A as first option & B as second. University A should accept 6 students with the highest points and the others should be accepted by University B.

Answer (score 0):

Use eloquent.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent (if that (5.5) is not the correct version of laravel you're using, you can change it in the top-right)